# Real Time Object Detection Delay Fails?

Tags: .net, aforge

I made an Object Detection application on c# by using aforge. I used  recorded video to find path of a fast ball, It looks working well, but when I try real time data (from cam directly) It fails. I have doubt that on recorded data when detection function in use It makes next frame wait, but on real time data If detection function in use we lost real time frames. detection function's ping about 60 msec - 80 msec..  I have about 500 msec to find path.

also not sure if this is the problem. If It is , should I make it queue or skip frames? 
or maybe I am wrong problem something else?

Comment: Are you using the AForge.Imaging.TemplateMatch class to detect your objects ?

Comment: yes TemplateMatch also but the function which makes delay is MotionDetector's ProcessFrame. TemplateMatch look's working fast enough.

Comment: Ok. I'm not familiar with AForge's MotionDetector but you should be aware that TemplateMatch isn't really reliable as the result isn't normalized. You should use EmguCV (OpenCV) MatchTemplate method instead, with any ..._NORMED template match type. Anyways, you should give more detail for your problem because it's hard to say if you skip frames or if TemplateMatch isn't finding the model in your images.